# Custom redirect on Google Sites

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, sites

I need a form that lets the user enter their email and have it redirect to a url that contains that email.  This has to live in Google Sites due to stupid restrictions by our IT department.

The url is going to be a google doc query - I can handle that part just fine.  This would be really simple to do in ASP, but google sites doesn't play nice with asp and I can't use free hosting/iframe solutions.